Subset a single row matrix/array and return row names
I have a matrix:
lil_matrix <- matrix(data = 1:4,
                  nrow = 2,
                  dimnames = list(c("Row1", "Row2"),
                                  c("Col1", "Col2")))

When I subset for a column, it returns a named numeric vector.
lil_matrix[,1]


If my matrix is one row and I subset for a column, the vector is unnamed.
lil_matrix[1, , drop = FALSE][,1]


I need this one row matrix to return a named vector when I subset for a column. Using the above example, it should return Row1 for the name and 1 for the value.
The solution needs to be as efficient as possible.
Thank you!

youre not going to get much more efficient than your answer, altho you can simplify the expression a bit setNames(lil_matrix[1, ], dimnames(lil_matrix)[[2]])[1] matrices have dimnames which vectors do not, and it's not obvious to the extractor how the object should be named, ie by rows and/or columns, so you're better off writing your own method that suits your needs

You'll find the following in the NEWS for R version 2.7.0:

Where an array is dropped to a length-one vector by drop() or [, drop = TRUE], the result now has names if exactly one of the dimensions was named.  (This is compatible with S.) Previously there were no names.

In your example, both dimensions are named, so the length-one result does not get names.  One "answer", then, is to remove the dimension names that you don't want before calling [:
> (x <- array(c(1L, 3L), c(1L, 2L), list("Row1", c("Col1", "Col2"))))
     Col1 Col2
Row1    1    3
> x[, 1L]
[1] 1
> `colnames<-`(x, NULL)[, 1L]
Row1 
   1

FWIW, help("drop") is actually wrong here.  It says,

If the result is a length-one vector, the names are taken from the first dimension with a dimname.

but that's not true in general.  I've filed a bug report here.

One possible solution is creating a new object for the subset matrix:
r1 <- lil_matrix[1, , drop = FALSE]

Then subsetting the columns:
rc <- r1[,1]

Then setting names to the vector:
names(rc) <- row.names(r1)

I am hoping for a more efficient solution that does not require creating two new objects.
